# How to reference SKSpriteNode without full instantiation in Swift3?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

Previously, I had been using `var progressBar = ProgressBar?()` right above `init` within one of my SKSpriteNode subclasses, to allow various methods to reference `progressBar` throughout the class like so:

```
class Ship:SKSpriteNode{

    var progressBar = ProgressBar?()

    static var shipState = "norm"
    var powerupOn = false
    var moveSpeed:CGFloat
    var lives:Int
    var canShoot = false

    let las = SKSpriteNode(texture:laserTexture)

    var gun:GenericGun = GenericGun()
    let scaleFactor:CGFloat = 0.07

    init(startPosition startPos:CGPoint, controllerVector:CGVector){

        self.lives = 3
        self.moveSpeed = 160

        super.init(texture: ship0, color: UIColor.clear, size: ship0.size())

        //Set position
        self.position = startPos

        attachGun(gun)
        self.setScale(scaleFactor)


        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: self.texture!, size: self.size)

        self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ship
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Alien
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = CGFloat(0)
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false //TBD

        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = controllerVector.dx * moveSpeed
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = controllerVector.dy * moveSpeed

        self.name = "ship"

        //Call animations
        self.animateShip1()
    }

    func updateVelocity(_ v:CGVector){
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = v.dx * moveSpeed
        self.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = v.dy * moveSpeed
    }

    func attachGun(_ gun:GenericGun){
        gun.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.addChild(gun)
    }

    func animateShip1() {
        let animate = SKAction.animate(with: shipFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(animate)
        self.run(forever)
    }

    func updateShipProperties(shipVelocity v:CGVector,laserStartPos laserStart:CGPoint){
        updateVelocity(v)

        progressBar?.position = CGPoint(x: self.position.x - (self.size.width/2 + self.size.width/7.0), y: self.position.y)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

In Swift3 I'm getting an error that I need to provide full arguments, is there a way to achieve this same functionality in Swift3?

Comment: why do you even need the init?  Do you have code in it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, this is all in my SpaceShip class. There are a ton of other methods/properties in this class but I omitted as I thought it would make the question more clear

Comment: well then write a proper init method,  you do not use init() with SKSpriteNode,  you use `init?(coder:aDecode:NSCoder)`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Maybe this is ultimately my problem-- I'm updating the question right now.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is it possible that I've been building my SKSpriteNode subclasses incorrectly and this has also been leading to CPU issues?

Comment: no idea, don't know what you are doing.  This is why we have timers and break points, and if you use the test project they provide, you could measure why things take so long

Comment: your init is a convenience init, you should be making it one.  see that fatalError, that is not something good to have in your code,  that is a note for you to make it, not a code for the end user.  if all else, just call `super.init(coder)` inside of that

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'll look into convenience initilizers right now, as I'm not fully sure what they do. Also, I don't know if I follow you on the fatalError-- I assumed that was just a safety, but you're saying that I shouldnt even have that as part of my subclass? Where would the second `super.init(coder)` go in this case? Thanks a lot for the advice

Comment: Also when using `convenience init(startPosition startPos:CGPoint, controllerVector:CGVector){` I draw the error: `convenience init for ship must delegate (with self.init) rather than chaining to a superclass initializer with ('super.init')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123482/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-sam).

Comment: Sam did you ever get initialisation wired?